# strange Segmentation fault (core dumped) on matrix

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault

So, I have this part of code:

```
for (lin = 0; lin < linhas_mat1; lin++)
{
    fgets(linha_s, MAX_LINHA, matriz1_file);
    buffer = strtok(linha_s, " ");
    for (col = 0; col < colunas_mat1; col++)
    {
        printf ("\nCOLUNA: %d", col);
        if (&matriz1[lin][col] == NULL)
            printf ("erro");
        matriz1[lin][col] = atoi(buffer);
        buffer = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
}
```

It puts a matrix from a file into the memory. The open and the allocation didn't give errors (at least I think). What's strange is that the error seems to occur (discovered by printing the number of the current line) on the last 2 elements (before the last with the code above or the last element if I add some prints, that's even stranger) and only if the matrix has 5 lines or more. The previous lines are added into memory without problem, so I can't see why the last elements give problems. Someone has a clue what's the problem or some tips in how I can find the issue?

Comment: How are the variables (particularly matriz1) declared?  The expression `&matriz1[lin][col]` should never be `NULL`.

Comment: `&matriz1[lin][col]` can never be `NULL` as no allocated memory is ever placed at address `NULL`.

Comment: I test it. more than once. `&matriz1[lin][col]` is never `NULL`. matriz1 is `int **matriz1;`

Comment: You should probably check `if (buffer == NULL)`. If your input has not enough elements on a line, `strtok` will return `NULL` before `col` has reached `colunas_mat1`.

Comment: Checked `if (buffer == NULL)`. It's never null and it still gives this error. It seems that it end the last for, but instead of exiting the loop it gives the error. It doesn't start the loop again. The error appear before a "printf" putted in the first line of the loop.

Comment: Use the debugger, Luke.

Answer (score 0):

The code itself has no problem. The only possible reason I can see is, when the input file has less columns than you specified, it will cause a segmentatioin fault.

Here is full version of your code, I only added some initializations

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

  int lin, col, linhas_mat1, colunas_mat1;

  char* buffer;
  char linha_s[1023];
  int matriz1[8][5];
  linhas_mat1 = 8; colunas_mat1 = 5;
  const int MAX_LINHA = 20;

  FILE *matriz1_file = fopen("aa.txt", "r");

  for (lin = 0; lin < linhas_mat1; lin++)
  {
    fgets(linha_s, MAX_LINHA, matriz1_file);

    buffer = strtok(linha_s, " ");
    for (col = 0; col < colunas_mat1; col++)
    {
      //printf ("\nCOLUNA: %d", col);
      if (&matriz1[lin][col] == NULL)
        printf ("erro");
      matriz1[lin][col] = atoi(buffer);
      printf("%d ", matriz1[lin][col]);
      buffer = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

If you give following file as input, the matrix will get all the values without any problem, unless you remove some column from it.

```
1 2 9 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
```